# Should community wiki answers be eligible for bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounty, community-wiki

I posted an answer to this question [Kepler conjecture: Are there only two most efficient packings or could there be more than two?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461620) summarizing various points made in the comments into a coherent series of paragraphs, to help the question-asker understand the extent to which these comments addressed their question.

I posted the answer as community wiki specifically because I didn't want to earn reputation for just re-iterating points made by others.

So I was surprised when I got 100 reputation points as a bounty award. I would've assumed community wiki answers wouldn't be eligible for those kinds of points, precisely because community wiki is often used as a way to not earn reputation.

**Question**: Should community wiki answers be eligible for bounty points like this?

Comment: On first thoughts, I don't think it's terrible. Someone might want to award a bounty to a particularly helpful answer. But it's less clear how such a bounty can or should be divided if there are multiple editors of an answer, particularly if subsequent edits by other users substantially improve the answer! Given that this is a network-wide software feature, it might be worth asking at meta.stackexchange at some point.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Concerning the suggestion to ask on [meta.se], I think it is worth checking out the existing posts [on this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki+bounties) first, to avoid possible duplication. 
For example, this one looks a bit similar: [Bounties on question with CW answer do not reward people for improving existing answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134003).
(Admittedly, CW-posts are often used on MO differently from other sites - as a reputation-denial mechanism. So this is at least to some extent site-specific.)